# calculating the percentage of categorical variables by items and time using tidyverse

Tags: r

I am analyzing time course data using R. It is from a eyetracking experiment. participants were instructed to fixate different regions of a pictural stimulus. We got five regions that are critical to our analysis: "cd","dd","u1","u2","whitespace". They are 5 factors of the variable "AOI names".  The whole time was aggregated into time bins (50ms each time bin).
Now I want to calculate the percentage of each region by Bin and Stimulus

An example of my data frame is below (sory, ctrl + k didn't work in my computer):

```
Stimulus Participant AOI names         Bin
1        P1              cd            1
1        P1              cd            2
1        P1              dd            3
1        P1              dd            4
1        P1              dd            5
1        P1              u1            6
1        P1              u1            7
1        P1              u2            8
1        P1              whitespace    9
1        P1              u2            10
2        P1              dd            1
2        P1              cd            2
2        P1              dd            3
2        P1              u1            4
2        P1              u2            5
2        P1              whitespace    6
2        P1              whitespace    7

...
1        P2              dd            1
1        P2              cd            2
1        P2              u1            3
1        P2              u2            4
1        P2              u2            5
1        P2              u2            6
1        P2              dd            7
1        P2              u2            8
1        P2              whitespace    9
1        P2              u2            10
2        P2              dd            1
2        P2              dd            2
2        P2              u1            3
2        P2              u1            4
2        P2              u2            5
2        P2              whitespace    6
2        P2              whitespace    7
```

What I want to get is:

```
Stimulus      time_bin      percentage  AOI names   
1                1            50%         cd     
1                1            50%         dd    
1                1            0%          u1    
1                1            0%          u2
...
1                2            100%         cd       
1                2            0%           dd    
1                2            0%           u1    
1                2            0%           u2
...
```

That is, in each stimulus and time bin, how many participants directed their looks to one AOI.

I tried the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

X1_u1 <- X1 %>% mutate(percentage = as.integer(X1[`AOI Name`], 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Stimulus,Bin)%>%
  summarise(percentage = mean(percentage))
```

Can you take a look which part of my code is wrong? Or do you have better solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide sample data using `dput` function and add desired results to your question?

Comment: What do you intend to do with `as.integer(X1[`AOI Name`], 1, 0)`?

Comment: Hi, @camille , Thanks for your comment! I would like to use this code to calculate the fixations of all participants on each AOI per stimulus and bin. I think [1,0] may allow me to get a ratio in the [1,0] interval. I just updated my question, what I would like to have is actually, among the whole participants, how many of them looked at one AOI (for example "cd") at one stimulus and bin. Do you have an idea? ;)

Comment: I'm just getting thrown off from where you're trying to go with that sort of syntax, and how that would get you to a percentage. Indexing a data frame with `[` will get you another data frame, not a vector